# MacBook Pro 13 2017: Built-in display flickering, stops when connecting to an external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, hdmi, gpu

My MacBook Pro's built-in display started flickering (screen goes black) a few weeks ago.
Most of the time the flickering stops by itself randomly after a couple of minutes.

The thing is, when I connect to an external display using HDMI, the flickering on the built-in display stops, and both displays function normally.

Are there any suggestions for troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue - specifically the display “mux” chip that handles the routing of video signals.  To diagnose this, it would require putting hands on with specialized tools.  You should take it in for service.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @MattSanders This was probably a problem with the connectors of the screen, which means that the whole screen needs to be replaced, so I ended up buying a new Macbook.