# MacBook Pro 13 2017: Built-in display flickering, no problem when connecting to an external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, hdmi

Same problem as [this problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453866/macbook-pro-13-2017-built-in-display-flickering-stops-when-connecting-to-an-ex)
"My MacBook Pro's built-in display started flickering (screen goes black) a few weeks ago. Most of the time the flickering stops by itself randomly after a couple of minutes.

The thing is, when I connect to an external display using HDMI, the flickering on the built-in display stops, and both displays function normally."
I already try with a new screen without change, as i can comment this post i republish a new thread

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a hardware issue with the graphics mux ([multiplexer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer)).  It’s a chip that manages the switching of the GPU signal to the internal and external displays (or both). When you use dual displays, the signal becomes synchronized, so to speak and thus stabilized.

There’s no software “tweak” for this, though there may be a bug in macOS driver (kext).  My suggestions are as follows:

- open a support ticket with [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com) to get this issue documented.
- Take it into an Apple store for warranty replacement

Comment: Umh, ok thanks, i will change the motherboard for now, the computer is for one of my customer, it is not under warrantly :/